# Show that $p=2$ and $q=3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Do there exist primes $p,q$ where $p\neq 2$, $q\neq 3$ and $p<q$ such that
>
> $p^2\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$?

I think the answer is no. Suppose there exists such a pair of prime $(p,q)$ such that $p^2\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

We need to show that $p=2$, $q=3$.

$p^2\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. We have
$p^2\equiv 1\pmod{q}\implies q\mid p+1$ and $p\mid q-1$.

How to show that $p=2$, $q=3 $ from here?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Then $pq$ is a divisor of $(p+1)(q-1)$.

Comment: How do you get $q\mid p+1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $q\mid (p^2-1)$ and $p\mid (q-1)$.

From the first condition, you have $q\mid (p-1)$ or $q\mid(p+1)$. The first cannot hold, because $p<q$. In the second case, you get $q=p+1$: indeed, $p+1\le q$ and $q\mid(p+1)$ imply $q=p+1$. If $p$ is odd, then $q$ would be even, which is impossible.

Comment: This question was used as a "test" in my review queue, and I was halfway through typing exactly this when it dawned on me. Haha. +1